# Performance issues on different machines

Tags: c++, performance, opencv

I wrote a C++ program that uses opencv, I compiled it in VisualStudio 2010 using release mode as Win32 application, the opencv library is dynamically linked so I just copied the needed dll's to the root folder of the program(so I can run it on other computers), the program is tracking people in a video and works fine when I run it on my computer, however when I run it on other machines it works but 65% slower, at first I thought that its the machine it self that is slow, but then I wrote another small program(the code is below) whose only purpose is to read a video file and play it approximately at the original video speed. Unfortunately I have the same issue with it as well, it runs fine on my computer but when I run it on other computers it slows down by 65%(more or less), I am new to c++/opencv and I have no real idea why this is happening I'm hoping some one can enlighten me, was the dynamic linking a bad idea? and I should compile opencv as a static library(which I don't yet know how to do and will appreciate any help on the issue). or is it something else?

```
#include "opencv\cv.h"
#include "opencv\highgui.h"


int main(){

    cv::VideoCapture vidBuffer;
    if(!vidBuffer.open("res/test.mp4")){
        std::cerr << "Cant find \"res/test.mp4\"\n";
        system("pause");
        return -1;
    }
    int fps = vidBuffer.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
    int frameTime = 1000/fps;

    //video loop
    cv::Mat frame;
    for(char c=-1;;c=cv::waitKey(frameTime)){
        if(!vidBuffer.read(frame)||c==27)
            break;
        cv::imshow("Vidoe test", frame);
    }
    //loop emd

    vidBuffer.release();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: maybe it's some installed components which are present on your machine and not on the other

Comment: check which dlls it uses and how it finds these dlls on your machine and on the other machines

Comment: @Ashalynd on my computer I have added the dll's dir to the path, I can only assume that the other computers are reading them from the root of the program it self(I don't know where the program looks first though, the path or the root?)

Comment: @Pandrei like what? the only thing I can think of is the optimisation visual studio does which is set to maximize speed.

Comment: Search path used by Windows to locate a DLL is: (1) the directory where the executable is located; (2) the current directory; (3) the Windows directory; (4) the directories listed in the PATH environment variable. So, probably :-), you are reading them from the root.

Comment: You can try checking how long it takes to read the frame. In any case, you shouldn't wait the same time for each frame because you don't know how long your code takes. You should take the start time and add to it every loop iteration the frame time to calculate the next frame time, then check how long you have until the next frame time arrives and wait only the gap (and not the entire frame time).

Comment: @manlio good to know thank you. indeed I assumed it's from the root, but can that really make that much of difference?

Comment: @selalerer I totally agree and I indeed wrote it as you recommend in the original application, I did write "approximately at the original video speed" just to check it out I don't think that the read function is delaying execution by as much as 65%.

Comment: Have you verified that the other computers don't have an innate 65% lower performance? Are you comparing like against like, or do the other computers have slower cpu/gpu parts? CpuZ and GpuZ are suitable test programs.

Comment: @enhzflep I thought that might be the issue, that's why I wrote the smaller program, I can understand that a huge application might run slower on other computers, the thing is that they both(the original big program and the small one) are 65% slower, and I thought the slow down should be relative to the code, which is not in that case since both programs run slower by 65%.
There might be a small difference between the computers but not 65%.
Nevertheless I'm leaning to agree with you that it's the computers who are slower since I cant really find a better explanation.

Comment: @Dima - you can also press "windows-key" + "pause-break" to bring up the windows dialog that tells you the specs of the computer. In my case, running win7 on a laptop, amongst other info, I get the following `"Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU   M330 @ 2.13GHz 2.13GHz"`. A potential thing to watch for, is that OpenCV can use both the cpu and gpu. Depending on the exact situation, a pc with a slower cpu may outperform a better cpu, since the slower pc has a better gpu. GpuZ can test for combined cpu/gpu capability. CpuZ and GpuZ allow direct comparisons between machines. GpuZ is better for openCV stuff.

Comment: @enhzflep didn't know about the gpu, and i'm sitting on a gaming beast, that just might be it!

Comment: @DimaMaligin - I think that's it indeed. As soon as I read `gaming beast` my immediate thoughts were "oh, well that solves _that_, then"! :-)